# Event on tapping out of a UITextView (i.e. UITextView losing focus)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'd like to perform some processing on my UITextView once the user has finished editing it and tapped somewhere else on the screen. What's the best practice?

I almost managed to get the desired effect with `func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView)` however this only runs when the user has tapped 'Enter' key on the keyboard (which people very rarely do - they just commit the changes by tapping on somewhere else on the screen.)

The problem with `func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)` is that it doesn't care whether the UITextView was edited or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add an UITapGestureRecognizer on the view which hold the textView. In the UITapGestureRecognizer's selector, you can add the logic codes to handle the process. You can check the length of the textView's text to determine the UITextView was edited or not. Here is some sample code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

func handleTap() {
    let text = textView.text
    textView.resignFirstResponder() // loosing focus

    if text.characters.count > 0 {
        // textView edited
    } else {
        // textView not edited
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the purpose of textView.resignFirstResponder()? Is there a more robust way of checking whether a textView has been edited?

Comment: The purpose of textView.resignFirstResponder() was to make the textView release the cursor focus on the view, and hide the keyboard if needed. I have no idea about other ways to check the textView edited or not.